# Complete password field scp command on linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Im writing a shell script to use the scp command (ssh) to transfer a file across to a computer. This obviously is password protected is there a way on either end to either...disable the password or to auto complete the password for the customer?

This out of pure convience and I have no idea if it is possible (im fairly new to linux), any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can generate a pair of RSA/DSA keys (public and private). In your terminal:

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

It will generate a pair of files:

- **Private key:** `.ssh/id_dsa`
- **Public key:** `.ssh/id_dsa.pub`

Then, if you have access to remote host, you can add your public key to `.ssh/authorized_keys` file. In your remote host, copy the public key and use the following command:

```
cat id_dsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 2):

You should you public key identification if you have access to SSH keys on both machines.

Comment: how abouts do I go about setting that up?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at ssh keys. [github](http://help.github.com/linux-key-setup/) has a nice intro